# Static initializer or static constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, static

I've been looking if there exists something like a static initializer in PHP.

Here is a static method as a Java example:

```
public class Foo {
    static {  //This is what I mean (Does this exist in other languages like PHP?
       //THIS IN PHP
    }
}
```

I found what it's name (static initializer). It is used the first time the Class its loaded. Seems like theres not static initializer in PHP.

Comment: yes, there's static methods in php, and no, that's no php - that's java. and no, there's no static "blocks" in php. methods can be static, class attributes (aka class vars) can be static, but not blocks of code. classes cannot contain bare code.

Comment: Those are not static methods, but static variables...

Comment: @MarcB you should make your comment an answer, because that's what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think PHP provides any direct ways to initialize classes like it's done in Java or C#. If you want to initialize static class members you can do it within a constructor, something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    private static $staticValue;

    public function __construct() {
        if (self::$staticValue === null){
            self::$staticValue = 'Nice';
        }
    }
}
```

However, the above approach won't work if you never instantiate your class. That means that accessing static class members won't trigger the code in `__construct` unfortunately, and I don't think there's any workaround for this problem in PHP.

Comment: Yep, thats right. Finally i decided to use 
`public static function init(){
Class::Foo = new Foo();
}`

That's the way i did it, the only problem i have to call init() but well. :·) 
Thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

Static properties and methods in PHP

```
class SomeClass {
    private static $property = 'Foo';

    public static function getProperty() {
        return self::$property;
    }
}

SomeClass::getProperty();
```

Non static properties and methods

```
class SomeClass {
    private $property = 'Foo';

    public function getProperty() {
        return $this->property;
    }
}

$class = new SomeClass();
$class->getProperty();
```

Comment: This is NOT a `static block`(initializer), it is only a method as `static`.